# BatchNormalization layer in keras leads to oscillating validation accuracy

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network, keras-layer, batch-normalization

I am trying to use BatchNorm layers for a image classification task but I am having trouble with the keras implementation.When I run the same network with BatchNormalization layers I get better training accuracy and validation accuracy but during training the validation accuracy oscillates strongly. Here are what the training surves look like.

[Training accuracy with batchnorm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/angrV.png)

[Training accuracy without batchnorm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XnWaR.png)

I have tried changing the batch size (from 128 to 1024), and changing the momentum parameter i the batchnorm layer but it doesn't change much.

I am using batchnorm inbetween conv/Dense layers and their activation layers.

I have also checked that the normalization axis is correct for conv layers (axis=1 with Theano).

Has anybody had similar issues? There are a look of issues posted about the keras implementation of batchnorm but I have not found a solution to this problem yet.

Thanks for any pointers or references to similar issues.

EDIT:
Here is the keras code I have used to build the mdoel but I have tried different architectures and different momentums:

```
    # create model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(20, (4, 4), input_shape=(input_channels,s,s), activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(5, 5)))
    model.add(Conv2D(30, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3)))
    model.add(GlobalAveragePooling2D())
    model.add(Dense(128))
    if use_batch_norm:
        model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=1, momentum=0.6))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(dropout_rate))
    model.add(Dense(nb_classes))
    if use_batch_norm:
        model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=1, momentum=0.6))
    model.add(Activation('softmax'))
```

Comment: Layer normalisation may be more robust than batch normalisation. For an implementation of layernorm in keras, see [this issue](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/3878).

Comment: It will be helpful if you give the detailed network architecture.

Comment: Sorry about the long delay.
@MPA I am really trying to get the BatchNorm keras layer to work before considering alternatives but thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: @user36624 I have added the keras code for the model structure

Comment: Could it be related to differences in how keras conducts batchnorm in training and validation mode? See [this blog post](http://ruishu.io/2016/12/27/batchnorm/) (for tensorflow models)

Comment: @MPA yea I think it is related to that but since keras has a global function for training which handles validation data I think it validation data should be handled like testing data no? The dropout layer is run in 'test_mode' for the validation data in keras at least.
I guess I have to look at the implementation of the batchNorm layer in keras and Theano to understand whats happening

Comment: @rob_m I'm running into a similar issue with batch normalization with pytorch. I've found that either disabling cudnn (for TensorFlow you can do this by setting the env var TF_USE_CUDNN to 0) or disabling the affine parameters of the batch normalization got rid of this issue.

Comment: @ssidorenko thanks I will look into that. I guess not using CUDNN slows down training quite a lot though no?

Comment: I found decreasing momentum helped a bit with this.

Comment: @Luke I've also found this- switching from Adam to Adadelta fixed the problem for me.